# Why is my asp-action calling the wrong action in my controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc

New to .net core, have an mvc .net core app where I set parameters in a partial view, click a "submit' button and get a list of data returned from CreateList action in my controller. This all works. I added a button "export to excel" and have an ExportToExcel action in the same controller but when I click the "export to excel" button, it goes to the "CreateList" action instead of "ExportToExcel" action.

I've tried input type=Submit and formaction = "CreateList" and "ExportToExcel" respectively. I tried button asp-action=CreateList and button asp-action=ExportToExcel but it always goes to CreateList action

cshtml:

```
<form asp-controller="CADIncidentData" method="post">
  <button asp-action="CreateList" asp-controller="CADIncidentData">View List</button>
  <button asp-action="ExportToExcel" asp-controller="CADIncidentData">Export To Excel</button>
</form>
```

Controller: CallIncidentData

```
[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult CreateList(CallData.allParameters c)
   {
     ...code to create the list
   }

[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult ExportToExcel(CallData.allParameters c)
   {
     ...code to export to excel
   }
```

I need the asp-action ExportToExcel to go to the ExportToExcel action in my controller, instead of going to "CreateList" in the controller where it is currently going.  I don't understand why it's NOT going there, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: If you switch places of you controller methods, does the `ExportToExcel` gets called ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the asp-controller attribute from the form? It shouldn't be needed as it's on the buttons, and maybe it's overriding the button actions and directing to the first action on the controller? Just a theory...

Comment: I switched the ExportToExcel action above CreateList and I removed the asp-controller attribute but both button clicks still call CreateList action...

Comment: The code is working as is. Do you have some special routings or routing attributes?

Comment: In my startup config this is what I have:

Comment: app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseStaticFiles();            

                app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });

Comment: I just ran the code and looked at the html when the code was running, and on that button, formaction is blank: <button formaction="">Export To Excel</button> on the other button is correctly has formaction="CADIncidentData/CreateList".

Answer (score 0):

Dumb mistake - didn't have 'public' on my actual action item (code I posted was simplified for the question). Added public and it works.